# Paranoia's 'with_deleted' command not working on Rails tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-paranoid, ruby-paranoia

I have the following task to run on Rais:

```
require 'net/http'
namespace :seed do

task :set_gid_on_histories => :environment do

    History.all.each do |hist|

        if hist.channel != "REMOTE"
            if hist.guest
                guest = Guest.find(hist.user_group_id)
                hist.update_attributes(:group_id => guest.group_id)    
            else
                ug = UserGroup.with_deleted.find(hist.user_group_id)
                hist.update_attributes(:group_id => ug.group_id)    
            end     

        end

    end
end

end
```

The problem happens in line

```
ug = UserGroup.with_deleted.find(hist.user_group_id)
```

What happens is that it's throwing

*ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find UserGroup with 'id'=71 [WHERE "user_groups"."deleted_at" IS NULL]*

just as if there was no 'with deleted' on the command line.

**I tried to type the same command on rails console and it worked, i.e. when I run ug = UserGroup.with_deleted.find(71) it works just fine and finds the deleted user.**

So it seems that paranoia's 'with_deleted' command is not working on rails tasks... Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?  You should be able to get around it by using `UserGroup.unscoped.find(hist.user_group_id)`

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.1.8. I tried unscoped as you said, but it was exactly the same: it works on rails console, but not on the task

Comment: I have a clue: I'm running the task with 'rvmsudo RAILS_ENV=production rake seed:set_gid_on_histories'. If I take out RAILS_ENV=production from it, it understands the with_deleted/unscoped commands (it worked on my local database)

Comment: But the problem persists because on my server I must use RAILS_ENV=production because my db is there. So the problem persists but its related to the Rails Environment

Comment: It's weird to me it would work like that only in one environment.  I think you'll need to file an issue with the gem's maintainer on github, including as much info as you can